# how can we add two field in same column in sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i want to create a database that consists all products rating and notes purchase by user

suppose that i create a table name "Users_rating_product" that consists some column

```
user_id ->INT
company->Varchar
product1 -> 3 (rating of product out of 5)|(review of product)
product2-> 4(rating)|(some review)
```

i want to know how can i do it in mysql . i'm using phpmyadmin for database creation

table looks like

```
user_id  | company  |Ac                 | TV           | fridge 

1        | goderaj  |3 ,take more power |4,less power  |5,efficient
```

i want to know how can i do this so that both rating and notes for product display in same column

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll need a separate table. Call it `ProductRating`. Put a unique key (`ID`) to the table and reference that key to your `Users_rating_product` table.

For example:

Users_rating_product:

```
user_id  | company  |Ac  | TV | fridge 
1        | goderaj  |1   | 2  | 3
2        | somecomp |4   | 5  | 6
```

ProductRating

```
ID | Rating | Review
1  | 3      | Take more power
2  | 4      | less power
3  | 5      | efficient
4  | 5      | excellent
5  | 1      | awful
6  | 3      | average
```

Comment: but there are many users and for any user there are many company then how can be relate which product have which review?

Comment: Your table need a `user_id`.

Comment: @SAC - I've added another user/company in my example to show you how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that you can achieve your functionality.
but this is not standard format to write queries.

```
you can have comma seperated column in your database like this
    user_id  | company  |Ac_mapping_id  
    1        | goderaj  |1,REview for Ac
```

for Seperate two values you can do like this

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(String,',','.'),2) 'Name'
```

for Detail Reference for splitting two values you can refer :
[click To refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Better Way is to store Product description in different table.
You can easily write queries to retrieve your data

```
user_id  | company  |Ac_mapping_id  | TV_mapping_id | fridge_mapping_id 
1        | goderaj  |1              | 2             | 3
```

& store all the ratings & reviews in mapping table like this

```
Ac_mapping_id  | Rating   |Review
1              | 1        |abcd
```

So on for the other table.

For Retrieving all the data just Use Left outer join

```
Select 
*
from
Users_rating_product mm
Left outer join  Ac_mapping_table ac on ac.ac_mapping_id = mm.ac_mapping_id
.....so on
```

Comment: @SAC This is one of the way of normalization of your database